# How to change color of a selected Tab of a TabBar [Flutter]?

Tags: flutter, tabbar

I try to implement this tab widget on Flutter.

[image: this]

I'm still struggled to figure out how to change the color of a Tab like that. I only know how to change the selected/unselected label color (not with the particular tab background).

[image]

Is there any way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet

Comment: Try https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_tab_bar

Comment: @GursewakSingh thx, this is what i need so far!